# any method for solving expressions according to BODMAS in python

Tags: python, eval

So I was creating my own programming language and the reason I am stuck right now is that I want my programming language to solve mathematical expressions according to the BODMAS rule, but it is a bit complex for me though (I don't know why to be honest) I used `eval()` function but that isn't working as it gives me this long long error or whatever in the world it is though

```
45
{'a': 45} []
18
{'a': 45, 'b': 18} []
{'a': 45, 'b': 18, '__builtins__': {'__name__': 'builtins', '__doc__': "Built-in functions, types, exceptions, and other objects.\n\nThis module provides direct access to all 'built-in'\nidentifiers of Python; for example, builtins.len is\nthe full name for the built-in function len().\n\nThis module is not normally accessed explicitly by most\napplications, but can be useful in modules that provide\nobjects with the same name as a built-in value, but in\nwhich the built-in of that name is also needed.", '__package__': '', '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, origin='built-in'), '__build_class__': <built-in function __build_class__>, '__import__': <built-in function __import__>, 'abs': <built-in function abs>, 'all': <built-in function all>, 'any': <built-in function any>, 'ascii': <built-in function ascii>, 'bin': <built-in function bin>, 'breakpoint': <built-in function breakpoint>, 'callable': 
<built-in function callable>, 'chr': <built-in function chr>, 'compile': <built-in function compile>, 'delattr': <built-in function delattr>, 'dir': <built-in function dir>, 'divmod': <built-in function divmod>, 'eval': <built-in function eval>, 'exec': <built-in function exec>, 'format': <built-in function format>, 'getattr': <built-in function getattr>, 'globals': <built-in function globals>, 'hasattr': <built-in function hasattr>, 'hash': <built-in function hash>, 'hex': <built-in function hex>, 'id': <built-in function id>, 'input': <built-in function input>, 'isinstance': <built-in function isinstance>, 'issubclass': <built-in 
function issubclass>, 'iter': <built-in function iter>, 'aiter': <built-in function aiter>, 'len': <built-in function len>, 'locals': <built-in function locals>, 'max': <built-in function max>, 'min': <built-in function min>, 'next': <built-in function next>, 'anext': <built-in function anext>, 'oct': <built-in function oct>, 'ord': <built-in function ord>, 'pow': <built-in function pow>, 'print': <built-in function print>, 'repr': <built-in function repr>, 'round': <built-in function round>, 'setattr': <built-in function setattr>, 'sorted': <built-in function sorted>, 'sum': <built-in function sum>, 'vars': <built-in function vars>, 'None': None, 'Ellipsis': Ellipsis, 'NotImplemented': NotImplemented, 'False': False, 'True': True, 'bool': <class 'bool'>, 'memoryview': <class 'memoryview'>, 'bytearray': <class 'bytearray'>, 'bytes': <class 'bytes'>, 'classmethod': <class 'classmethod'>, 'complex': <class 'complex'>, 'dict': <class 'dict'>, 'enumerate': <class 'enumerate'>, 'filter': <class 'filter'>, 'float': <class 'float'>, 'frozenset': <class 'frozenset'>, 'property': <class 'property'>, 'int': <class 'int'>, 'list': <class 'list'>, 'map': <class 'map'>, 'object': <class 'object'>, 'range': <class 'range'>, 'reversed': <class 'reversed'>, 'set': <class 'set'>, 'slice': <class 'slice'>, 'staticmethod': <class 'staticmethod'>, 'str': <class 'str'>, 'super': <class 'super'>, 'tuple': <class 'tuple'>, 'type': <class 'type'>, 'zip': <class 'zip'>, '__debug__': True, 'BaseException': <class 'BaseException'>, 'BaseExceptionGroup': <class 'BaseExceptionGroup'>, 'Exception': <class 'Exception'>, 'GeneratorExit': <class 'GeneratorExit'>, 'KeyboardInterrupt': <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>, 'SystemExit': <class 'SystemExit'>, 'ArithmeticError': <class 'ArithmeticError'>, 'AssertionError': <class 'AssertionError'>, 'AttributeError': <class 'AttributeError'>, 'BufferError': <class 'BufferError'>, 'EOFError': <class 'EOFError'>, 'ImportError': <class 'ImportError'>, 'LookupError': <class 'LookupError'>, 'MemoryError': <class 'MemoryError'>, 'NameError': <class 'NameError'>, 'OSError': <class 'OSError'>, 'ReferenceError': <class 'ReferenceError'>, 'RuntimeError': <class 'RuntimeError'>, 'StopAsyncIteration': <class 'StopAsyncIteration'>, 'StopIteration': <class 'StopIteration'>, 'SyntaxError': <class 'SyntaxError'>, 'SystemError': <class 'SystemError'>, 'TypeError': <class 'TypeError'>, 'ValueError': <class 'ValueError'>, 'Warning': <class 'Warning'>, 'FloatingPointError': <class 'FloatingPointError'>, 'OverflowError': <class 'OverflowError'>, 'ZeroDivisionError': <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, 'BytesWarning': <class 'BytesWarning'>, 'DeprecationWarning': <class 'DeprecationWarning'>, 'EncodingWarning': <class 'EncodingWarning'>, 'FutureWarning': <class 'FutureWarning'>, 'ImportWarning': <class 'ImportWarning'>, 'PendingDeprecationWarning': <class 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>, 'ResourceWarning': <class 'ResourceWarning'>, 'RuntimeWarning': <class 'RuntimeWarning'>, 'SyntaxWarning': <class 'SyntaxWarning'>, 'UnicodeWarning': <class 'UnicodeWarning'>, 'UserWarning': <class 'UserWarning'>, 'BlockingIOError': <class 'BlockingIOError'>, 'ChildProcessError': <class 'ChildProcessError'>, 'ConnectionError': <class 'ConnectionError'>, 'FileExistsError': <class 'FileExistsError'>, 'FileNotFoundError': <class 'FileNotFoundError'>, 'InterruptedError': <class 'InterruptedError'>, 'IsADirectoryError': <class 'IsADirectoryError'>, 'NotADirectoryError': <class 'NotADirectoryError'>, 'PermissionError': <class 'PermissionError'>, 'ProcessLookupError': <class 'ProcessLookupError'>, 'TimeoutError': <class 'TimeoutError'>, 'IndentationError': <class 'IndentationError'>, 'IndexError': <class 'IndexError'>, 'KeyError': <class 'KeyError'>, 'ModuleNotFoundError': <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, 'NotImplementedError': <class 'NotImplementedError'>, 'RecursionError': <class 'RecursionError'>, 'UnboundLocalError': <class 'UnboundLocalError'>, 'UnicodeError': <class 'UnicodeError'>, 'BrokenPipeError': <class 'BrokenPipeError'>, 'ConnectionAbortedError': <class 'ConnectionAbortedError'>, 'ConnectionRefusedError': <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, 'ConnectionResetError': <class 'ConnectionResetError'>, 'TabError': <class 'TabError'>, 'UnicodeDecodeError': <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>, 'UnicodeEncodeError': <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'>, 'UnicodeTranslateError': <class 'UnicodeTranslateError'>, 'ExceptionGroup': <class 'ExceptionGroup'>, 'EnvironmentError': <class 'OSError'>, 'IOError': <class 'OSError'>, 'WindowsError': <class 'OSError'>, 'open': <built-in function open>, 'quit': Use quit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit, 'exit': Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit, 'copyright': Copyright (c) 
2001-2023 Python Software Foundation.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2000 BeOpen.com.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 1995-2001 Corporation for National Research Initiatives.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam.
All Rights Reserved., 'credits':     Thanks to CWI, CNRI, BeOpen.com, Zope Corporation and a cast of thousands
    for supporting Python development.  See www.python.org for more information., 'license': Type license() to see the full license text, 'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.}} ["['a', '+', 'b', '/', '2']"]
```

So like, is there any method to fix this or any method to solve the mathematical equations according to BODMAS in python?

```py
        if res == "DEFINE_INT":
            ans = rep_int(ans)
            iddn = ans.index(":")
            Variables.update({ans[:iddn]: int(ans[iddn+1:])})
            return Variables, True
        elif res == "DEFINE_STR":
            ans = rep_int(ans)
            iddn = ans.index(":")
            Variables.update({ans[:iddn]: ans[iddn+1:]})
            return Variables, True
        elif res == "READ_INPUT_INT":
            x = int(input())
            Variables.update({ans: x})
            return Variables, True
        elif res == "READ_INPUT_STR":
            x = input()
            Variables.update({ans: x})
            return Variables, True
        elif res == "SOLVE":
            eval(ans, Variables)
            return ans, False
```

First it checks if user has defined variables or want to take input then it stores it in Variable set, after that if user wants to solve mathematical equation he needs to use `output sol *equation*` in order to solve it, so yep that's what I am trying to do